# Thymelaf: Require the correct thymeleaf syntax to call fragments by using a?b:c logic

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I havce a date picker that will allow the user to select date. The datepicker code is present below:

```
<form  id="formBean" th:action="@{/dailyStatistics}"  th:object=${dataFormBean} >
                        
                                    <!--<h1 class="card-title m-0"  >Select Range Date </h1>-->Select Range Date
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm daterange" title="Date range">
                                       <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                                   </button>
                                   
                                  From:  <input type="text" readonly="readonly"   id="selectSdateInput"  th:field="*{selectSDate}" >
                                  To:  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="selectEdateInput"  th:field="*{selectEDate}" >
                                    
                           </form>
```

I have 2 thymeleaf fragments:
1.fragments/dailyStatisticsFragments :: dailyStatisticsFragmentsToday
code:

```
<div id="fragments-container" th:replace="fragments/dailyStatisticsFragments :: dailyStatisticsFragmentsToday"></div>
```

2.fragments/dailyStatisticsFragments :: dailyStatisticsFragmentsAll
code:

```
<div id="fragments-container" th:replace="fragments/dailyStatisticsFragments :: dailyStatisticsFragmentsAll"></div>
```

I want to implement a?b:c concept for the below requirement in thymeleaf:
If the user is not picking any date. The system has to select

```
fragments/dailyStatisticsFragments :: dailyStatisticsFragmentsToday
```

else if the user is picking any date. The system has to select

```
fragments/dailyStatisticsFragments :: dailyStatisticsFragmentsAll
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was able to resolve the above By using this synatx.

```
<div id="fragments-container">
    <div th:replace="fragments/dailyStatisticsFragments :: ${dataFormBean.selectSDate == null and dataFormBean.selectEDate == null} ? 'dailyStatisticsFragmentsToday' : 'dailyStatisticsFragmentsAll' "></div>
</div>
```